# sql to get count of cases assigned to each id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My sql output should look like,

```
AssignedTo  Cases
Larry       3
Tom         1
Henry       1
```

I have 3 tables with the foll. relationship

```
select
     CASE
            WHEN r.id = 30 THEN r.name
            ELSE r.name
                 || ' '
                 || u.b_id
        END
    AS assignedto,  count(*) as cases
    from cases c, users u, roles r
    where c.id = u.b_id and
          c.assigned_to = u.id and 
          u.role_id = r.id
          and c.b_id = 40 
    group by c.assigned_to;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a simple `COUNT()` aggregation

```
SELECT assigned_to, COUNT(*) AS cases
  FROM tab
 GROUP BY assigned_to
```

**Update :**

In this case(*in order to include the names from another table*), use a Select Statement with an `[INNER] JOIN` :

```
SELECT u.name AS assignedto, COUNT(*) AS cases
  FROM cases c
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = c.assigned_to
 GROUP BY u.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Count ... group by id, assigned_to.

Comment: move to comments

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT to aggregate and GROUP BY to assign the aggregation to a group.

```
SELECT
  assigned_to
  COUNT(id) as cases
  FROM
  <your_table_name_here>
 GROUP BY assigned_to
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `COUNT`.
The COUNT() function returns the number of rows that matches a specified criterion. And `GROUP BY` clause groups records into summary rows.
The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

```
Select AssignedTo, count (*) as cases from table group by  AssignedTo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,sum(assigned_to) as Cases from s1 group by id;
id  Cases
1   29232
2   7654
```